# Using AsyncTask in ListView adapter (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am developing an app where I am using List View adapter to inflate my list view items. What I observed  is that my GUI is not that responsive because I am inflating image view along with text view in each of my list items. And the number of items depend on the number of images in the users device. So it is doing a lot of work and I am also getting message saying "Skipped ~63 frames..." like that.

Below is my complete code of the List View adapter class file named Adapter_PhotosFolder.java:

```
public class Adapter_PhotosFolder extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();


    public Adapter_PhotosFolder(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        //Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.size() + "");
        return al_menu.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.apftv1);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.apftv2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.apfiv);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setText(al_menu.get(position).getStr_folder());
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setText(al_menu.get(position).getAl_imagepath().size()+"");


        Glide.with(context).load(al_menu.get(position).getAl_imagepath().get(0))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);

        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;
    }


}
```

If I am not wrong we can use thread or preferably an AsyncTask to avoid GUI freezing. I could not figure out how to implement that in my case.

***My Question :*** Can you tell me how can I use an AsynTask in my case to make it smooth.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use an asynctask. Create a bitmap in doInBackground. Place the bitmap in the UI in onPostExecute().

Comment: You can also use a thread to get a bitmap and place the bitmap with runOnUiThread.

Comment: But everybody else wil tell you that you have to use Glide or another library.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: That didn't solve my problem @blackapps. It still stucks a little bit. By the way, I am already using glide.

Comment: Very fine that you did not post any code. We consider it done then.

Comment: I have already explained that I am using Grid View Adapter to inflate grid view with image views that will be containing images from gallery and that it's slow.

Comment: And if I did miss upon something then you can tell me, I will post that part of the code.

Comment: I have updated my question.Tell me how can I use AyncTask that in my code.

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand that the Glide call would block. It should not block and hence no need to use a thread or async task. Your code looks ok.

Comment: Just do a test without the Glide call. Is it responsive then?

Comment: It's the same @blackapps. Could it be because I am loading a lot of images from the storage? Can I do something like images will load a bit slow in the grid view so that things don't get piled up and there is no load on device's memory. Like first image will load and then a wait for say ~500ms and then next image will load like that?

Comment: If it is the same without the Glide call then your problem has nothing to do with images. That should be  clear then.

Comment: okay, thanks for the help @blackapps